List all months between two dates in R
I'm trying to add the list of month and year between two dates.
I have the following dataset:
PKID    Name    Gender  DateStart   DateEnd
68      PAUL    1       24/11/2021  23/02/2022
68      PAUL    1       24/04/2022  23/06/2023
40      KATE    2       01/01/2000  14/03/2000
40      KATE    2       03/12/2000  31/01/2001

And I Want to create the following dataset:
PKID    Name    Gender  DateStart   DateEnd     year    Month
68      PAUL    1       24/11/2021  23/02/2022  2021    11
68      PAUL    1       24/11/2021  23/02/2022  2021    12
68      PAUL    1       24/11/2021  23/02/2022  2022    1
68      PAUL    1       24/11/2021  23/02/2022  2022    2
68      PAUL    1       24/04/2022  23/06/2023  2022    4
68      PAUL    1       24/04/2022  23/06/2023  2022    5
68      PAUL    1       24/04/2022  23/06/2023  2022    6
40      KATE    2       01/01/2000  14/03/2000  2000    1
40      KATE    2       01/01/2000  14/03/2000  2000    2
40      KATE    2       01/01/2000  14/03/2000  2000    3
40      KATE    2       03/12/2000  31/01/2001  2000    12
40      KATE    2       03/12/2000  31/01/2001  2001    1

Where month corresponds to the month between the star date and the end date and year correspond to the month.
I have tried the following:
# Load necessary libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate) # For handling date operations

# Sample data 
df <- read.table(text = "
PKID    Name    Gender  DateStart   DateEnd
68  PAUL    1   24/11/2021  23/02/2022
68  PAUL    1   24/04/2022  23/06/2023
40  KATE    2   01/01/2000  14/03/2000
40  KATE    2   03/12/2000  31/01/2001
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Convert date columns to Date format
df$DateStart <- dmy(df$DateStart)
df$DateEnd <- dmy(df$DateEnd)

# Generate sequence of dates for each row
df <- df %>%
  group_by(PKID, Name, Gender, DateStart, DateEnd) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(DateStart, DateEnd, by = "month")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(Date),   # Extract year
    Month = month(Date)  # Extract month
  ) %>%
  select(-Date)  # Remove the temporary Date column

# Print the result
print(df)

But I get the following error:
Error in reframe():
ℹ In argument: complete(data = pick(everything()), ..., fill = fill, explicit = explicit).
ℹ In group 1: PKID = 40, Name = "KATE", Gender = 2, DateStart = 2000-01-01, DateEnd = 2000-03-14.
Caused by error:
! object 'DateStart' not found


You can try:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(date = map2(DateStart,  rollforward(DateEnd), \(x, y) seq(x, y, by = "month"))) |> 
  unnest(date) |> 
  mutate(year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         date = NULL)

# A tibble: 26 × 7
    PKID Name  Gender DateStart  DateEnd     year month
   <int> <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    11
 2    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    12
 3    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2022     1
 4    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2022     2
 5    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     4
 6    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     5
 7    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     6
 8    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     7
 9    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     8
10    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     9
# ℹ 16 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Or alternatively with reframe()
df |> 
  reframe(date = seq(DateStart, rollforward(DateEnd), by = "month"),
          year = year(date),
          month = month(date),
          .by = everything()) |> 
  select(-date)


This won't work if the EndDate falls on the same day as the StartDate. Replace 23/02/2022 in the first row with 24/02/2022.  You get an extra month.

@Edward - nice catch. Fixed.

Thanks for teaching me rollforward - I learned something today!

An alternative using nest.
df |>
     nest(data=c(DateStart, DateEnd), .by=c(PKID, Name, Gender, DateStart, DateEnd)) |>
     mutate(date=sapply(data, \(x) unique(
       c(seq.Date(x$DateStart, x$DateEnd, by="month"), x$DateEnd))),
                     year=sapply(date, year),
                     Month=sapply(date, month)) |>
     unnest(c(year, Month)) |>
  select(-c(data, date))


# A tibble: 26 × 7
    PKID Name  Gender DateStart  DateEnd     year Month
   <int> <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    11
 2    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    12
 3    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2022     1
 4    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2022     2
 5    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     4
 6    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     5
 7    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     6
 8    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     7
 9    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     8
10    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     9
# ℹ 16 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


In base R, we can add a "list" column using seq.Date in Map with strftime to months. Next, we make data.frames out of say PKID and the respective months lists, that we rbind and finally merge to the original data frame.
> dat |>
+   transform(...=Map(seq.Date, DateStart, DateEnd, by='month') |> 
+               lapply(strftime, '%m') |> list() |> list2DF() |>
+               setNames('mlst')) |> 
+   with(Map(data.frame, PKID=PKID, months=mlst)) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> merge(dat, sort=FALSE)
   PKID months Name Gender  DateStart    DateEnd
1    68     11 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
2    68     11 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
3    68     12 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
4    68     12 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
5    68     01 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
6    68     01 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
7    68     04 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
8    68     04 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
9    68     05 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
10   68     05 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
11   68     06 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
12   68     06 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
13   68     07 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
14   68     07 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
15   68     08 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
16   68     08 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
17   68     09 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
18   68     09 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
19   68     10 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
20   68     10 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
21   68     11 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
22   68     11 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
23   68     12 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
24   68     12 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
25   68     01 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
26   68     01 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
27   68     02 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
28   68     02 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
29   68     03 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
30   68     03 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
31   68     04 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
32   68     04 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
33   68     05 PAUL      1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23
34   68     05 PAUL      1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23
35   40     01 KATE      2 2000-01-01 2000-03-14
36   40     01 KATE      2 2000-12-03 2001-01-31
37   40     02 KATE      2 2000-01-01 2000-03-14
38   40     02 KATE      2 2000-12-03 2001-01-31
39   40     03 KATE      2 2000-01-01 2000-03-14
40   40     03 KATE      2 2000-12-03 2001-01-31
41   40     12 KATE      2 2000-01-01 2000-03-14
42   40     12 KATE      2 2000-12-03 2001-01-31
43   40     01 KATE      2 2000-01-01 2000-03-14
44   40     01 KATE      2 2000-12-03 2001-01-31

Note that you need proper data format in the columns. As this is basic knowledge, I have included it in the data section below.

Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(PKID = c(68L, 68L, 40L, 40L), Name = c("PAUL", 
"PAUL", "KATE", "KATE"), Gender = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), DateStart = c("24/11/2021", 
"24/04/2022", "01/01/2000", "03/12/2000"), DateEnd = c("23/02/2022", 
"23/06/2023", "14/03/2000", "31/01/2001")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> date_cols <- c('DateStart', 'DateEnd')
> dat[date_cols] <- lapply(dat[date_cols], as.Date, '%d/%m/%Y')


I have done few changes in your approach to make it work.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         Date = DateStart) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  complete(PKID, Name, Gender, DateStart, DateEnd, 
           Date = seq(DateStart, DateEnd, by = "month")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(Date),  
    Month = month(Date) 
  ) %>%
  select(-Date, -row)

# A tibble: 22 × 7
#    PKID Name  Gender DateStart  DateEnd     year Month
#   <int> <chr>  <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    11
# 2    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2021    12
# 3    68 PAUL       1 2021-11-24 2022-02-23  2022     1
# 4    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     4
# 5    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     5
# 6    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     6
# 7    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     7
# 8    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     8
# 9    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022     9
#10    68 PAUL       1 2022-04-24 2023-06-23  2022    10
# ℹ 12 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Thanks . It works however the last month is missing in list . Like for the start date 24/11/2021 and end date  23/02/2022, we have the output for month 11 and 12 for 2021 and only month 1 for 2022. The month 2 is missing in the output.
